# How to create one ID that contain multi infomation with 4 bytes

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

It is rather complex, so i need to explain:

I have a struct, this struct was used a long time, used to read/write binary file. So can't add new or remove any field in this struct. But when I create this struct, i have put a spare into this struct in order to reused in the feature. Now, this struct is:

```
struct Entry {
 int a;
 int b;
 ....
 char spare[4];
};
```

There are 4 bytes in my struct now.
I need to create ID entry base on 3 informations below:

- Time: (month and year, year was format as YY, month is MM).
- Code: code of entry, it contain 3 character, example: ABC.
- Values: values of entry, it is float type, include 4 numeral at integral and decimal part. example: 1.21, 40.14 or 12.3.

Base on 3 information above, how to create 1 ID Entry that contain in 4bytes adequately. Thanks a lot of.

Note: I have a way:

- Time: assume 12/99 encode to 12*100+99 = 1299
- Code: assume ABC encode to 'A' + 'B' + 'C' = 65 + 66 + 67 = 198.
- Values: assume 40.25 encode to 40.14*100 = 4014.

After that, i encode 3 numbers 1299, 198, 4014 to:

ID_Entry = (1299 * 10^7) + (198*10^4) + 4014 = 1299 198 4014 = 12.991.984.014. But this ID_Entry is too large to contained in 4 bytes spare

You have any way or improve my way, please tell me, help me, thanks a lot of.

P/S: So create ID therefore can't duplicate, in the same Time (month + year) Code and Values don't duplicate, if ts isn't same Time, Code and Values can duplicate.

Comment: What is the required range of your Time and Code values?  Is the set of valid three letter Code values fixed and known? If so, how many entries are in that set?

Comment: + Time contain month (00 to 11) + year (any year).
 + Code: contain any 3 character (A -> Z, 0 -> 9, example AB8 or 07R).
A lot of entry, it is about 10000 entries, thanks.

Comment: Then as Rob's answer says, you can't do it.  You need to re-examine your requirements - for example is it *really* necessary to support a range of 100 years? Do you *really* need to support 36 possible characters in the three digit code?

Answer (score 3):

You can encode data into bitfields.

e.g. month and year: month is 0-11, so you need 4 bits. Allow say 7 bits for a year (you can add a constant like 2000 to get the actual year).

That's 11 bits

3 character code: If the code is just A-Z, you can do each one in 5 bits (3*5 = 15)

= 26 bits, but that only leaves 6 bits for the id, which isn't enough to handle the range you want.

Bits in the byte would look like:

```
MMMM_YYYY  YYYA_AAAA  BBBB_BCCC  CCII_IIII

Where M=Month, Y=Year, A=Code1, B=Code2, C=Code3, I=Id
```

Comment: Excellent advice from a maintainability perspective, but wasteful of space. Using 4 bits for the month leaves invalid values, wasting space. Ditto 7 bits for 100 years, 5 bits for 26 letters, etc. +1, anyway.

Comment: Having a reference tables could reduce the number of required bits even further. If certain char codes are not available, say "AAA" is available and range from "AAB" to "ABB" is not, than we can index "AAA" = 1, "ABC" = 2. Same can be applied to other data.

Comment: Both good comments. @Robᵩ: took the approach that since the OP doesn't seem to know much about bit fields etc, a simple packing of fields to bits would be easiest to explain. Michael Sh: I read the question "as data" as in he wanted to use the 4 bytes in the struct to hold the ID. Sure you can use the 4 bytes to index to somewhere else, but I assumed that wasn't what OP wanted. Short answer is unless OP does something better than I've suggested, it's not all going to fit ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot of to Rob, Michael Sh and John

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to fit 20 lbs of potatoes in a 10 lb sack.

Consider all of the possible values of the ID, assuming 26 letters, 100 years of months, and values from 00.01 to 99.99. There are `26*26*26 * 1200 * 10000` possible values, or 210,912,000,000 distinct combinations. Since there are only 4,294,967,296 distinct values for a 32-bit int, you cannot possibly represent all of the values, no matter what encoding you choose.

What you *can* do is to reduce some of those numbers. Maybe three digits instead of four? Maybe the letters A through M instead of A through Z? Maybe recording the month only instead of year and month?

For example, if you restrict the value to two digits, you can encode thusly:

```
id = (char1 - 'A');
id = id * 26 + (char2 - 'A');
id = id * 26 + (char3 - 'A');
id = id * 26 + (year * 100 + month);
id = id * 1200 + (int)(value);
```

2,109,120,000 possible combinations. More than an entire bit to spare!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your struct has more than 4 bytes.
2. A float has 4 bytes, a char has 1 byte, your time format could be stored inside 2 maybe 1 byte.

Just do the math by yourself if I understood you correct you have at least 21 bytes of information you want to store in 4 bytes without collision. That's impossible!

In some cases you could optimize the size if you can limit the input data, for example only 16 different chars are possible or only floats between 0 and 1 are allowed but still what you want to achieve from what you wrote is not possible.